# FbLogin using FBSDK Sometimes working very Slow

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk

Don't make it as a duplicate question, I raise this question because the answers are not helpfull,
The integration works fine for me, but the pages loads really slow.

It takes really a long time to load the login screen. Login action takes more than 8-50 seconds or more.

Sometimes for loading authentification screen takes more than 10 secs.

The Following code is for FBLoginButtonAction

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!){

        if(error != nil){

            print(error.localizedDescription)

            return

        }

        if result.isCancelled{

            showAlert(title: "Login Cancelled", message: "You have cancelled login through Facebook")

        }

        if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil{

            print("Logged in")

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make FBlogin using NSNotification method.
Just follow below steps.

1. set FBDelegate and set observer for NSNotification in ViewDidload like,

   ```
   self.btnFBLogin.delegate = self
   self.btnFBLogin.readPermissions = ["public_profile","email","user_friends"]

   FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "getUserProfile:", name: FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
   ```

2.Now make one custom function for NSNotification like,

```
   func getUserProfile(notification : NSNotification)
{
    let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
    if(accessToken != nil)
    {

        let req = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name"], tokenString: accessToken.tokenString, version: nil, HTTPMethod: "GET")
        req.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            if(error == nil)
            {
                print("result \(result)")
                let userInfo = result as AnyObject
                if let email = userInfo.valueForKey("email") as? NSString
                {
                    print(email)
                }
                else
                {
                    let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
                    loginManager.logOut()
                }
            }
            else
            {
                print("error \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Note : Don't write any logic in FB delegate method. Just put it there.

I think this will help u bcz it works fine for me. :)